# Element arcticle not allowed as child of element main in this context

Tags: html

I have this code and I'm using this HTML validator to check it: https://validator.w3.org

When I've put this code through it, one error that appeared was:
*Element arcticle not allowed as child of element main in this context*
which I don't really understand.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vuestras mascotas</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="inicio.html" target="_self">Inicio</a>
            <a href="informacion.html" target="_self">Informacion</a>
            <a href="formulario.html" target="_blank">Formulario</a>
            <a href="vuestrasmasc.html" target="_self">Vuestras mascotas</a>
            <a href="faq.html" target="_self">FAQ</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <h1>Vuestras mascotas</h1>
        <arcticle>
            <h2>Estas son alguna de vuestras mascotas:</h2>
            <section>
                <h3>PatoLucas</h3>
                <p>Subespecie: Anatino</p>
                <p>Hola! Me llamo PatoLucas. Soy un pato de 4 años! Me gusta mucho nadar en la piscina y soy un poco
                    travieso jijiji. Me encanta graznar a las 05:00am y despertar a mi familia.</p>
                <img src="imagenes/pato1.png" alt="PatoLucas" width="250" height="250">
            </section>
            <section>
                <h3>Paquito</h3>
                <p>Subespecie: Tardonino</p>
                <p>Mi nombre es Paquito. Soy un pato que le encanta viajar en furgoneta con sus dueños. Mi ultima
                    aventura ha sido recorrernos todo Europa en furgoneta. Sigueme en mi canal de youtube
                    @paquitoViajerito y se mi nuevo amigo de aventuras.</p>
                <img src="imagenes/pato2.png" alt="Paquito" width="250" height="250">
            </section>
            <section>
                <h3>Lazo</h3>
                <p>Subespecie: Mergino</p>
                <p>Encantada :) me llamo Lazo. Soy una patita de Portugal que le encanta robar lazos. Soy mas bien
                    tranquilita, y me gusta quedarme en el sofa sentada junto a mi familia. Me gusta mas la comida de
                    mis dueños que la mia, pero no me suelen dar :(</p>
                <img src="imagenes/pato3.png" alt="Lazo" width="250" height="250">
            </section>
        </arcticle>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <p>© 2021 Tyler de Mier</p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the full error message from validator.w3.org:

```
Error: Element arcticle not allowed as child of element main in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
From line 22, column 9; to line 22, column 18  
>↩        <arcticle>↩
```

Here's line 23:

```
<main>
    <h1>Vuestras mascotas</h1>
    <arcticle>  <-- Line 23
        <h2>Estas son alguna de vuestras mascotas:</h2>
```

Very simply: "arcticle" isn't a valid HTML element name.  It's probably just a typo.  Try changing it (and the end tag) to [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article)

Comment: Doesn't seem worth more than a comment and a vote to close.

Comment: @Shikkediel: you can't format a comment.  I thought it would useful not just to point out the error (obvious, in retrospect), but also to show the OP how I found the error by looking more carefully at the error message.  [Teaching how to fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day._Teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime), as it were.  It's probably a waste: neither of us have heard back from the OP one way or the other...